# Parsing addresses from a blob of text in dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use a library called pyap to parse addresses from text in a dataframe column.

My dataframe df has data in the following format:

```
MID TEXT_BODY
1   I live at 4998 Stairstep Lane Toronto ON   
2   Let us catch up at the Ruby Restaurant. Here is the address 1234 Food Court Dr, Atlanta, GA 30030
```

The package website gives the following sample:

```
import pyap
test_address = """
   I live at 4998 Stairstep Lane Toronto ON   
    """
addresses = pyap.parse(test_address, country='CA')
for address in addresses:
     # shows found address
        print(address)
```

THe sample return it as a list but I would like to keep it in the dataframe as a new column

The output I am expecting is a data frame like this:

```
MID   ADDRESS                                     TEXT_BODY
1     4998 Stairstep Lane Toronto ON              I live at 4998 Stairstep Lane Toronto ON   
2     1234 Food Court Dr, Atlanta, GA 30030       Let us catch up at the Ruby Restaurant. Here is the address 1234 Food Court Dr, Atlanta, GA 30030
```

I tried this:

```
 df["ADDRESS"] = df['TEXT_BODY'].apply(lambda row: pyap.parse(row, country='US'))
```

But this does not work. I get an error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Apply` is indeed the right direction.

```
def parse_address(addr):
    address = pyap.parse(addr, country = "US")
    if not address:
        address = pyap.parse(addr, country = "CA")  
    return address[0]

df["addr"] = df.TEXT_BODY.apply(parse_address)
```

The result is:

```
   MID                                          TEXT_BODY  addr
0    1           I live at 4998 Stairstep Lane Toronto ON  4998 Stairstep Lane Toronto ON
1    2  Let us catch up at the Ruby Restaurant. Here i...  1234 Food Court Dr, Atlanta, GA 30030
```